# Oracle APEX проход по элементам Checkbox Group

Tags: plsql, checkbox, oracle19c, oracle-apex, apex

мне нужно в App Builder'е ORACLE APEX сделать функцию вставки данных сразу в несколько таблиц. Interactive report отображает информацию из View, собранного из таблиц "Book", "Autors_list", "Autor", где "Autors_list" нужна для раскрытия связи много ко многим между автором и книгой.

Так вот, на автоматически созданной форме я пытаюсь при нажатии на кнопку CREATE с помощью динамического события добавить данные в таблицы "Book" и "Autors_list".

**Данные, которые я пытаюсь добавить:**

***P15_ID_BOOK*** - id книги - добавить в "Book" и в "Autors_list"

***P15_BOOK_NAME*** - название книги - добавить в "Book"

***P15_AUTORS*** - авторы - представлены с помощью *Checkbox Group* - мне нужно пройтись по каждому его элементу и для каждого элемента добавить запись в "Autors_list" в виде (P15_BOOK_NAME, id автора из P15_AUTORS)

***P15_PUBLICATION_DATE*** - дата публикации - добавить в "Book"

***P15_PRICE*** - стоимость - добавить в "Book"

CheckBox Group задан при помощи следующего List of Values

```
select "id_autor", (CONCAT(CONCAT(autor."Name", ' '),autor."Surname")) as "Autors" from "Autor" autor;
```

Я написал следующий PL/SQL код для добавления в таблицы вышеперечисленных значений:

```
begin
insert into "Book"
("Name", "Publication_date", "Price")
values
(:P15_BOOK_NAME, :P15_PUBLICATION_DATE, :P15_PRICE);

FOR i IN (select autors."id_autor" from table(apex_string.split(:P15_AUTORS, ':')) autors)
LOOP
  insert into "Autors_list"
  values (:P15_ID_BOOK, i);
END LOOP;
end ;
```

однако мне выдает ошибку

> ORA-06550: line 7, column 22: PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "AUTORS"."id_autor": invalid identifier

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно проходить циклом по элементам Checkbox Group и доставать оттуда значения

Comment: Вместо `autors."id_autor"` используйте `column_value` или *

Comment: Добрый день!

Я использовал как column_value, так и *,

Мне выдало ошибку: ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Comment: Зачем вам : перед названиями полей? : - это имя bind переменных.

Comment: А как мне тогда обратиться к элементам страницы? Например, я пробовал обращаться к P15_ID_BOOK используя двойные кавычки и не используя ничего. Мне выдавало "ORA-06550: line 5, column 43: PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here"